# Xml image referencing trouble

Tags: xml

probably a real quick fix or small problem, so i'll cut straight to the point. I've created a small xml and attached xsl file for a catalogue table that **i want to fill with information and images**.

The entire table is working perfectly **except for displaying the image portion of it**, and i can't seem to figure out if it is because of XML in general (still entirely new to it), or due to some form of minor mistake I've made. Thanks for any pointers!

XML

```
<CATALOG>
<PLANT>
    <NAME>
        <COMMON>Pastel Roses</COMMON> 
        <BOTANICAL>Hybrid Rosa</BOTANICAL> 
    </NAME>
    <OCCASION>Formal/Wedding</OCCASION>
    <COLOURS>Summer pastel colours</COLOURS>
    <PRICE>$60.99</PRICE>
    <PHOTO><img src="images/plant1.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></PHOTO>
</PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

XSL

```
<table>
                <tr>
                      <th>Product Name</th>
                      <th>Botanical Name</th>
                      <th>Occasion</th>
                      <th>Colours</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                      <th>Photo</th>
                </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/PLANT">
               <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="NAME/COMMON"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="NAME/BOTANICAL"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="OCCASION"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="COLOURS"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="PHOTO"/></td>
                </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>


                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="PHOTO"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="PHOTO/img"/>
```